What do Shastras say about earning money?
Are we allowed to earn money? Or should I be content with the money I already have. What should I do with the money I earn? Am I supposed to donate a particular percent of my earnings?

'Are we allowed to earn money' - What sort of nonsensical question is that ?

@অনু afaik shudras are not allowed to amass wealth

There are 4 purusharth which are

Dharma
Artha
Kama
Moksha

In the bhagavatam shukracharya ji maharaj says

Therefore one who is in full knowledge should divide his accumulated wealth in five parts — for religion, for reputation, for opulence, for sense gratification and for the maintenance of his family members. Such a person is happy in this world and in the next.(8.19.37)

